# Can't get simple PreferenceFragment example to work

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, fragment

I'm struggling with using PreferenceFragments, can't seem to get it to work.

I have one preferences file, named at.package.preferences (without GUI) to save internal values - this works.

Now I wan't to create a preference screen for other (public) settings for the user, but here's where I fail.
My code:

```
    public class ChartPreferences extends Activity {

        private SharedPreferences prefs;
        private Button btn;

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_chart_preferences);

            prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

            btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.prefs_chart_content, 
            new ChartPrefsFragment()).commit();

            btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Toast.makeText(ChartPreferences.this, getLineSize(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();                
                }
            });

        }

        public int getLineSize()
        {

            return Integer.valueOf(prefs.getString(getString(R.string.line_size_key), Helper.PREF_DEFAULT_LINE_SIZE));
        }

        public static class ChartPrefsFragment extends PreferenceFragment
        {
            @Override
            public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.chart_prefs);  
            }           

        }
    }
```

So the preference screen shows and when I select a value, let's say 5, from the preference list, it's also ok. When I open the preferences list again, the 5 is still selected (so the preferences get saved - somewhere...)

Now the problem occurs in the getLineSize() function, when I try to access the saved value. It gives me a android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException.

I don't know where the values of the PreferenceScreen get saved, but it seems like it is not in the defaultSharedPreferences (?)

Here's my chart_prefs.xml, just in case:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <PreferenceCategory android:title="@string/chart" android:summary="@string/chart">
        <ListPreference android:entries="@array/prefs_line_size" android:title="@string/line_size" android:summary="@string/line_size" android:key="@string/line_size_key" android:entryValues="@array/prefs_line_size"/>
    </PreferenceCategory>

</PreferenceScreen>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems pretty weird to be using android:key="@string/line_size_key", ie the name of your preference is a resource lookup. I haven't looked at the code for Preference but perhaps it doesn't resolve the string but just uses '@string/line_size_key' as the token under which the preference is saved.

You don't really want the name of your preference to be a resource lookup do you? It means the preference would disappear as the user changed languages on their device.